# Transit visa for self transfer layover at Kuwait airport

Tags: transit, airport-transfer, kuwait

I have planned a trip to Egypt from India. For this we have booked tickets with Kuwait Airways from Mumbai India. We have a 5 hour layover at Kuwait. Our next flight is with Jazeera Airways from Kuwait to Cairo (J9731)on 14.10.2023.  We are arriving at Kuwait in Terminal 4 by Kuwait Airways but my departure is from Terminal 5 after self transfer. While returning also we have a layover in Kuwait. But this time our arrival and departure is from same Terminal.
We would like to know whether we would require a transit visa for this layover. Please guide us in this matter.